# Function of libwayland is deprecated – alternative?

Tags: c++, deprecated, wayland

I'm playing around with Wayland. Currently I'm trying to write a small compositor. The compiler keeps telling me that "wl_client_add_resource" is deprecated. What is the alternative to it?

Answer (score 0):

Should be wl_client_add_object() as shown [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-July/msg00119.html)

Updated:
As shown in [doxygen page of Wayland  1.9.90](https://people.freedesktop.org/~whot/wayland-doxygen/wayland/Server/wayland-server_8h.html#aa4a7f557f07314dc86a76b94c61e12bb) , wl_client_add_object and wl_client_add_resource all are deprecated.